# Why do i get the null value in database?

Tags: php, yii2

```
public function actionEvent()

{
    $event= new Events();
    $address=new Addresses();
    if($event->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $event->save() && $address->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $address->save())
    {

        echo $event->name;
        return $this->render('sucess',['event'=>$event]);

    }
    else{
        return $this->render('event',[
            'event'=>$event,
        'address'=>$address,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I don't get the record that i have posted in view form ,i get the null in database.why?

Comment: Database have a null value by default. If you wish set some other value as a default you can do it by setting default value while u structure the table.

Comment: Be specific. What do you mean by `NULL`.

Comment: when i submit my form everything goes well but when i see database in every field the record are null

Comment: Null on the entire row or null on a specific value in a row?

Comment: Can you update your question and show us your models?

Comment: null in every field excet the field 'id' which has auto increment

Comment: show your rules and your scenarios function. E.g. if your account is not allowed to set the attribute the default value in the db is used (e.g. null depending on the table column settings in your DB). In your $_post the value is set but it is not set in your model via the `load` function. You can also check this by echo this attribute after the load call.
BTW are you sure that your success view is rendered? I wonder are the event and address models are in a relationship.

Comment: ya sucess view is rendered and both the models are iin relation tooo

Answer (score 2):

I think you should indicate the name of the form element  you want load inside the model

Given that the [yii2 load documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load%28%29-detail)

> `public boolean load ( $data, $formName = null )`
>
> The form name to use to load the data into the model.   If not set,
>    formName() is used.

And in this case the form-name don't match the model

try this way

```
if($event->load(yii::$app->request->post('event')) && $event->save() && $address->load(yii::$app->request->post('eddress')) && $address->save())
```

or you should get the value from

```
 load($_POST['event']) 

 load($_POST['address'])
```

and the assign properly for your propose.

Comment: i have solved my problem but it is still understandable for how it solve ,i simply removed the declaration for variable in the model and it worked but how????

Comment: If you declare variables in model these don't are the same of the active record. In this case  when you save the active record variable are empty while the added variables are full but not saved.

Comment: But just for my knowledge my answer you helpful or not?